# How to access Windows share from an iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, windows, sharing, smb

I didn't find any iPad app that's supporting samba.

What is the best way to access Windows shares from an iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to the OPlayer app suggested by @Jason Salaz I've found several other apps that can connect to Windows smb shares:

- [Cloud Connect Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-connect-pro/id409964704) $14.99
- [FileBrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545) $3.99
- [Files Connect](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/files-connect/id404324302) $3.99
- [NetPortal](http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/netportal-access-files-on/id323133602) $2.39
- [ezShare Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ezshare-pro/id301589535) $15.99

Unfortunately I couldn't find any free apps.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no normally-accessible local filesystem on an iOS device, an app that "supports SMB" doesn't tell us enough. Because you can't simply copy files from a SMB share onto the iOS device.

There are plenty of apps that support SMB shares, three I can think of off the top of my head (at least as far as I recall) are: [Goodreader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html), [OPlayer](http://www.edavs.com/OPlayer.shtml), and [Air Sharing](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing).

Air Sharing is probably the most compatible for whatever you want to do, as it opens almost anything. Goodreader is primarily a document reader (txt, pdf, etc.), and OPlayer is a multi-format video player. It plays almost anything, MPEGs, AVIs, MKVs, etc.

What you want to accomplish beyond merely 'connecting to a SMB Share' will dictate the app you'll be able to use.

Comment: Thank you!
OPlayer supports connecting to Samba Windows shares. In Goodreader and Air Sharing I didn't find such functions.

Comment: How do you use an SMB share in GoodReader?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to hook up dropbox--not quite the same as you are asking but supported on pc/mac/iphone/ipad/android/linux/... and really does a great job of syncing your files together.

I haven't seen any other apps that would allow you to accomplish the goal you are after, but you will find some that will let you stream media from a certain type of media share--but that's not what you asked.

Comment: The apps I've posted above allow accessing Windows shares.

Answer (score 0):

The files app on iOS and iPadOS can connect to network file servers directly so there’s no need for a third party app unless you want features they provide over Apple’s native SMB client solution.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206481

(This wasn’t implemented when the question was asked, but it’s a great solution for now.)